# USB-C charging stopped working when computer is turned on

Tags: usb-c, charging

I have an issue with HP Pavilion laptop running kubuntu 20.04 - today it stopped charging via USB-C cable. USB-C still works fine, I connect my phone and laptop can charge my phone and open files, but when I tell my phone to charge laptop or just plug it into wall the laptop doesn't charge anymore (previously did).

I've tried updating to latest kernel now (5.12.11-051211-generic), and the bios doesn't appear to have any updates (F.10).

I tried holding down power button for 30 s, no dice. Not sure what else to try.

Also - it charges via USB-C when the power is off and lid is closed, just not while the computer is on.

Comment: Try in a live session. If the problem persists it rules out OS.

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was? I am experiencing the absolute same on Xubuntu 20.04 (5.4.0-89-generic) on an HP Elitebook

Comment: @user1252280 nope. Works fine in docking Station. Charges fine when powered off with regular usb-c charger. But doesn't charge while powered on with regular usb-c charger ‍♀️

Comment: Thanks @jwinterm ! Huge meh to the whole situation, but thanks! :)